# How to modify cell after WPF DataGrid is bound

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to update the look of a cell in a WPF data grid, I am coming from ASP.NET Webforms but i can't find a DataBound or something like that I can tap into to make changes. How does this work in WPF?

All i have is this:

```
 private void BindItems(Cars model)
 {
      ObservableCollection<CarItem> items = model.GetCarItems();
      CarsGrid.DataContext = items;

       // I tried updating below this line but the rows are not there yet (obviously), 
       // I was hoping there was like a CarsGrid.DataBind(); or something.
  }
```

This is the mark up of the checkboxes, basically i want to enable Buy, if the binding value is true and if it is true disable Rent, same the other way if Rent is true, then disable Buy

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Add" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Buy}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Remove" Width="75"  Binding="{Binding Rent}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Data in WPF's DataGrid is more like a sealed can,we cant modify it in the DataGrid itself.But what we are strongly recommended to do is 'Modify the Data Source'.Since you got a 'CarList typeof List<CarItem>' and bound it to the DataGrid,when you change the one 'CarItem.Name (eg)',the row which represent the Item you just changed will automatically accept which means the column that was bound with the 'CarItem.Name' property in this Row will changed.Plz check @SKleanthous's answer,it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to enable and disable stuff in Datagrid is the same as with every other item in WPF, simply set the IsEnabled property on whatever item you want. In your case you need to set the cell style to be used so as to override the template used to show the checkboxes* and a button (in my example).

*: Normally the checkbox template used in DataGridCheckBoxColumn will require one click to select the row and one click to toggle the value, while with the method shown below a single click will do.

Please see the following example with two checkboxes enabling and disabling two buttons. Obviously the two checkboxes need not be visible; they are databound to your data. If you require complex logic between the values of the bools, then you can either do it in code, or use a Converter to set the visibility of each item based on the context.

View:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="BuyTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Buy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="RentTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Rent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BuyButtonTemplate">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding Buy}" Content="BUY NOW!" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RentButtonTemplate">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding Rent}" Content="Rent this car!" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid Name="CarGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsBuy" Width="75" CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BuyTemplate}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="IsRent" Width="75"  CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RentTemplate}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Buy" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BuyButtonTemplate}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Rent" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=RentButtonTemplate}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-behind:

```
class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool buy, rent;
    public bool Buy 
    {
        get { return buy; }
        set { SetAndNotifyIfChanged(ref buy, value); }
    }
    public bool Rent 
    {
        get { return rent; }
        set { SetAndNotifyIfChanged(ref rent, value); }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Car(string name, bool isBuy)
    {
        Name = name;
        buy = isBuy;
        rent = !isBuy;
    }

    private void SetAndNotifyIfChanged<T>(ref T original, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
        where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        if (!original.Equals(newValue))
        {
            original = newValue;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And I set the items like this:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

cars.Add(new Car("Citroen", true));
cars.Add(new Car("Ford", true));
cars.Add(new Car("Toyota", false));

CarGrid.ItemsSource = cars;
```

Answer (score 2):

Please see Style.Triggers property. You can do something like this (see text marked with stars):

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Add" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Buy}">
    **<DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=YourPropertyName}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>**   
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Remove" Width="75"  Binding="{Binding Rent}">
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderStyle>
</DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```